# Android App crashes on older devices

Tags: android, gradle

My app works perfectly on my phone. On some older devices it crashes though:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blub.bla/com.blub.bla.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2572)
...
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at 
...
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_google_plus_icon.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0700ab
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2872)
...
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: invalid color state list tag gradient
    at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:217)
    at 
...
```

I checked other posts and most of the time it had something to do with gradle, and I can say that i have `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` set.

**Gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blub.bla"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'RestrictedApi'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.+'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

    implementation 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Edit:
activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                >
                <com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:id="@+id/fb_share_button"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sm_twitter"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_twitter_bird_logo"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sm_facebook"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_f_icon_color"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sm_twitter"
                    />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sm_gplus"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_google_plus_icon"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sm_facebook"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_filter"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <include
                layout="@layout/filter_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Does anyone know how to fix that? :(

Comment: Can you also add the code for the layout that `MainActivity` is using?

Comment: Sure, its in now

Comment: Perhaps the older devices do not have the resource `ic_google_plus_icon.xml` available? you might want to check to see if that resource is available before trying to access it.

Comment: That's a resource I found on the official website https://material.io/icons/. Added the svg File as a vector graphic to my drawable folder so anyone installing the app should be able to access it right?

Comment: If you added it manually to you project in the `drawable` folder then it should work. You might want to look inside the xml file to see if an item is in the file that cannot be interpreted by the older android versions.

Comment: @Barns I just installed a virtual device running on MinSDK Version 19. The application crashed instantly. It turned out that the SDK 19 cannot handle my background (shape with gradient -> Resource is not a Drawable). So I removed the background and was able to start it without crashing. Going to the next screen I'm getting the errors I posted initially still.

Comment: Try replacing the `ic_google_plus_icon.xml` in your layout file with something else to see if the error goes away.

Comment: Indeed something must've been wrong with that graphic. Replacing it with another random resource fixed at least that problem.

Answer (score 2):

**First Problem**: I had some resources in `drawable/v21` instead of `drawable` (not easy to see, since it's showing the same folder in Android studio, just with a `(21)` next to the file name

**Second Problem**: Use `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:background` or `android:res`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use gradients in vector drawables until 24 API.

About `android:fillColor`, for example, from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html:

> Specifies the color used to fill the path. May be a color or, for SDK 24+, a color state list or a gradient color

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you try to show an SVG in an Android version under 21, you can use AppCompatImageButton instead of ImageButton or AppCompatImageView with app: srcCompat

Comment: Using ImageButton with app:srcCompat seems to work as well

Answer (score 0):

For providing a general solution, IMO (and in my case), older versions are more strict about checking null data,resources,etc... and newer api versions seem more tolerant in contrast. Here is a good article about how to deal with null values.
[Avoid Check for Null Statement in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-avoid-null-check)